# Unable to build Boost.Python

Tags: boost, build, boost-python

I am trying to build `boost.python` following this [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/building.html#overwrite).
When I try to compile using `./b2` or `./bjam`, I am getting errors like:

```
error: No best alternative for /python_for_extensions 
next alternative: required properties: <python>2.6 <target-os>linux 
    matched 
next alternative: required properties: <python>2.6 <target-os>linux 
    matched
```

The error disappears when I added this line:

`using python : 2.6 : /usr/bin/python2.6 : /usr/include/python2.6 : /usr/lib/python2.6 : <python-debugging>on ;`

in

`/home/kchaitanya/boost/boost_1_50_0/tools/build/v2/user-config.jam`

However, when compiling now, I get compile time errors of *not being able to find header files.* Just a small excerpt of the errors is:

```
 ...patience...
 ...patience...
 ...found 1548 targets...
 ...updating 62 targets...
 gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.1.2/release/link-static/threading multi/numeric.o

 In file included from ./boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13,
             from ./boost/python/numeric.hpp:8,
             from libs/python/src/numeric.cpp:6:
 ./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 ./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:75:24: error: patchlevel.h: No such file or directory
 ./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:78:2: error: #error Python 2.2 or higher is required for 
 ./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:142:21: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 ./boost/python/instance_holder.hpp:34: error: ‘PyObject’ has not been declared
 ./boost/python/instance_holder.hpp:41: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘(’ token
 ./boost/python/instance_holder.hpp:45: error: ‘PyObject’ has not been declared
 ./boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:21: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
 ./boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:23: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
```

Need help on building this boost.python.

Comment: But, actually python is already installed in my system right ?

Comment: I tried installing `python-devel`. But, it din't solve my problem. Again it is giving the same old errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not installing the `python-devel` or `python-dev` package corresponding to my python version.

In my case it was python2.6 so

`sudo yum install python26-devel` did the trick.

Comment: sudo yum install -y python27-devel, also tried python2.7 pthon-2.7 all gave the same message No package python-2.7-devel available. On my redhat 7. try to find it: yum search python | grep -i devel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215535/how-to-install-python27-devel-on-centos-6-5

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in my project and above would not help. I was cross-compiling python and boost, and the actual issue for me was duplication of the 'using python : ' in configuration (one existed in project-config.jam, following the bootstrap.sh/bat execution and I was trying to add another python config myself to a user-config.jam).

This solution was described in here:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.build/22088

and here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-developers-archive/namMFSO_6Rg