# How to install python27-devel on Centos 6.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, centos6

I have installed python 2.7.6 from source, but can't find how to install python-devel for python 2.7

```
yum install python27-devel
```

doesn't work. How to install it?

Comment: I followed this link: http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/ and it worked just fine for me. Try that and please let us know what you had got! Cheers!

Comment: Python 2.7 has been installed and works very well, but this question about installation python27-devel package.

Comment: The devel package contains header files necessary for compilation of native binding in Python modules. Note that, when installing Python 2.7 from source using the `./configure && make && make install`  trinity, there is no python27-devel package available. CentOS 6.x does not have Python 2.7 included. If you want to build an .src.rpm or package that depends on Python 2.7 sources, you should make those sources include the sources/headers from your local install. [Please also read CentOS notes on source installs](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/SourceInstalls)

Comment: the above comment should be the accepted answer as each of the questions below only provide 1. a python 2.6 devel version and 2. a standalone python version, neither answer the question

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. First of all, if you try to run `yum install python27-devel`, then you should get the message like this:

```
No package python27-devel available
```

Then I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546676/how-to-install-python2-6-devel-package-under-centos-5),

```
yum search python | grep -i devel
```

This will show you that you have `python-devel.x86_64` package available if your OS is a 64 bit OS. If I am correct, then the following command should work fine as shown in the accepted answer:

```
yum  install python-devel.x86_64
```

Comment: `yum install python-devel` should be enough

Comment: After installing python-devel I still don't have the Python.h in /usr/include/python2.7/. Where does the header go?

Comment: You can't find package if additional repositories not enabled.

Answer (score 9):

I run Centos 6.5 on Virtualbox and this command solved it.

```
# yum update
# yum install centos-release-SCL
# yum install python27
```

Comment: that's not the development version

Comment: `yum install python27-python-devel.x86_64`