# error trying to install python-devel

Tags: python

When I try to install python-devel, it keeps giving me this error. Downgrade is also not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$yum install python-devel

Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.6-37.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-37.el6_4 for package: python-devel-2.6.6-37.el6_4.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-devel-2.6.6-37.el6_4.x86_64 (baseos_repo)
           Requires: python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-37.el6_4
           Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-52.el6
           Available: python-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64 (baseos_repo)
               python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-36.el6
           Available: python-2.6.6-37.el6_4.x86_64 (baseos_repo)
               python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-37.el6_4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215535/how-to-install-python27-devel-on-centos-6-5

Comment: Does that mean I will have to upgrade to python 2.7?. I am using python 2.6 that came installed with cent os.

Comment: If you haven't got any dependencies based on 2.6 you should upgrade to 2.7

Comment: That's what i ended up doing finally to resolve it. Upgraded to 2.7. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Python3 in the F23 repos is 3.4.3-6.fc23 from the F23 "updates" repository

Code:

> dnf list python3 python3-devel --enablerepo=updates-testing Last
>   metadata expiration check: 0:29:48 ago on Sat Apr 23 18:21:25 2016.
>   Installed Packages python3.x86_64
>   3.4.3-6.fc23                    @updates Available Packages python3.i686                            3.4.3-6.fc23
>   updates  python3-devel.i686                      3.4.3-6.fc23
>   updates  python3-devel.x86_64                    3.4.3-6.fc23
>   updates

Run the command

Code:

```
dnf list installed python3
```